# Akka.Persistence issues after updating to 1.3.1.0

Tags: c#, akka.net, akka.net-persistence

Everything worked just fine .... then I decided to update to AKKA.NET to 1.3.1.0...

Got many issues, and resolved them, however I can't seem to find solution to this last one (I hope). Error Message:

> ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void
>   Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Snapshot.QueryConfiguration..ctor(System.String,
>   System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String,
>   System.String, System.String, System.TimeSpan)'.
>          at Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotStore..ctor(Config
>   config)

Please help. Complete log is below (replaced IP with XX):

```
> [ERROR][9/7/2017 1:44:56 PM][Thread 0007][akka://ECHO3DEV/system/akka.persistence.snapshot-store.sql-server] Error while creating actor instance of type Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotStore with 1 args: (  class : "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotStore, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"
  plugin-dispatcher : akka.actor.default-dispatcher
  table-name : _SnapshotStore
  schema-name : dbo
  auto-initialize : on
  connection-string : "Data Source=XX.XX.16.XX;Initial Catalog=ECHO3DEV;Integrated Security=True"
)
Cause: [akka://ECHO3DEV/system/akka.persistence.snapshot-store.sql-server#1885464091]: Akka.Actor.ActorInitializationException: Exception during creation ---> System.TypeLoadException: Error while creating actor instance of type Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotStore with 1 args: (  class : "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotStore, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"
  plugin-dispatcher : akka.actor.default-dispatcher
  table-name : _SnapshotStore
  schema-name : dbo
  auto-initialize : on
  connection-string : "Data Source=XX.XX.16.XX;Initial Catalog=ECHO3DEV;Integrated Security=True"
) ---> **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Snapshot.QueryConfiguration..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.TimeSpan)**'.
   at Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotStore..ctor(Config config)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Akka.Actor.Props.ActivatorProducer.Produce()
   at Akka.Actor.Props.NewActor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Akka.Actor.Props.NewActor()
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.CreateNewActorInstance()
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.<>c__DisplayClass109_0.<NewActor>b__0()
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.UseThreadContext(Action action)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.NewActor()
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.Create(Exception failure)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.Create(Exception failure)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.SysMsgInvokeAll(EarliestFirstSystemMessageList messages, Int32 currentState)
[ERROR][9/7/2017 1:44:56 PM][Thread 0007][akka://ECHO3DEV/system/akka.persistence.journal.sql-server] Error while creating actor instance of type Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal with 1 args: (  class : "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"
  plugin-dispatcher : akka.actor.default-dispatcher
  connection-string : "Data Source=XX.XX.16.XX;Initial Catalog=ECHO3DEV;Integrated Security=True"
  connection-timeout : 30s
  schema-name : dbo
  table-name : _EventJournal
  auto-initialize : on
  timestamp-provider : "Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Journal.DefaultTimestampProvider, Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common"
  metadata-table-name : _Metadata
)
Cause: [akka://ECHO3DEV/system/akka.persistence.journal.sql-server#578824267]: Akka.Actor.ActorInitializationException: Exception during creation ---> System.TypeLoadException: Error while creating actor instance of type Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal with 1 args: (  class : "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"
  plugin-dispatcher : akka.actor.default-dispatcher
  connection-string : "Data Source=XX.XX.16.XX;Initial Catalog=ECHO3DEV;Integrated Security=True"
  connection-timeout : 30s
  schema-name : dbo
  table-name : _EventJournal
  auto-initialize : on
  timestamp-provider : "Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Journal.DefaultTimestampProvider, Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common"
  metadata-table-name : _Metadata
) ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Journal.QueryConfiguration..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.TimeSpan)'.
   at Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal..ctor(Config journalConfig)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Akka.Actor.Props.ActivatorProducer.Produce()
   at Akka.Actor.Props.NewActor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Akka.Actor.Props.NewActor()
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.CreateNewActorInstance()
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.<>c__DisplayClass109_0.<NewActor>b__0()
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.UseThreadContext(Action action)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.NewActor()
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.Create(Exception failure)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.Create(Exception failure)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell. 
 SysMsgInvokeAll(EarliestFirstSystemMessageList messages, Int32 currentState)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using `Akka.Persistence.SqlServer`, which is not up to date with Akka.Persistence v1.3 yet - you may track the progress [here](https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Persistence.SqlServer/pull/73).

Also after upgrade it will require executing an update script, as new `SerializerId` column will be added, it will be attached once new version of Akka.Persistence.SqlServer will be ready - read [v1.3.1 release notes](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/releases/tag/v1.3.1) for more details.

Comment: So what should i do now? Should I roll-back all AKKA.NET libs to older version or just the Persistence part? Also which of the old versions is most robust and working? Thank you

Comment: For those who have the same problem: goto Nuget manager and downgrade AKKA.NET to 1.2.3 (it'll downgrade all depending packages). Also if you're using Hyperion serializer downgrade it to 0.92